# Falcon 9 CGT Force?

Tags: launch, falcon-9, saturn-v, rcs, antares

Curious how much force the Falcon 9 cold gas thrusters produce for steering? I've seen numbers in the range of 25--100 lbf, but not sure where in this range (or outside it) the Falcon 9 falls.

If you know the numbers for other rockets, I'd be interested in those too. The Falcon 9 uses them for attitude control no reentry for landing, so my guess is that only modern rockets with landing first stages will have them...

Thanks if you know and can share!

Comment: No cold gas thrusters on the Saturn V AFAIK

Comment: Ah, thanks for the reminder, @OrganicMarble. Falcon 9 uses them for attitude control on reentry for landing, which most rockets don't do, so it makes sense the Saturn V wouldn't have them. The Antares probably doesn't have it either. I guess that restricts the question to the Falcon 9. I'll edit.